# JIRA Component invisible while creating new JIRA ticket

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I've created a new JIRA project 'A' and inside the project I've created three components 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'.

When I create new JIRA ticket for project 'A', I can not see any option to choose the component(s).

I am using `JIRA Version: 6.4-OD-05-008.`

is there anyone who knows what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the field is not visible or that you have a field with "none" next to it instead of a dropdown list?

Comment: @serakiel: yes exactly, field is not visible. It's even not visible in configure field option (on bug creation page), where you have option to "Show All Fields or Show Custom fields".

Comment: Take a look at your screen setup within the admin panel (jira administration -> issues -> screens) Take a look at what screen scheme is project A using and see if any of these screens have the component field in them.

Comment: try to use "Where is my field" helper function on create issue dialog, it will tell you where the field is missing